# Docker - pass argumens to service with docker compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Consider I have `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
my-service:
    build:
        context: my-service/.
        args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
    command: -my-some-argument 100 %CONSUMER_ARGS%
    networks:
        - custom-network
```

`docker-compose.yaml` is called via shell:

```
> docker-compose up
```

Argument `my-some-argument` is passed to container properly. But somehow, environment variable `%CONSUMER_ARGS%` is not replaced with proper value (literal string `%CONSUMER_ARGS%` is passed to container). So is there other way to pass arguments to my container while calling `docker-compose up`? Dokcer is running windows, containers under linux images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environmental variables in compose like this:

```
my-service:
    build:
        context: my-service/.
        args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
    command: -my-some-argument 100 ${CONSUMER_ARGS}
    networks:
        - custom-network
```

Note the `${}` instead of `%%`

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Your templating syntax for env variable replacement is not correct.
Use

```
${ENV_PASSED_VALUE:-DEFAULT_VALUE}
```